# Django No module named eventlog

Tags: django, event-log

I just downloaded the Pina-Project-Account from [here](http://pinaxproject.com/pinax/starter_project_list/).

I tried to `python manage.py runserver` and it started telling me `No module named...`; I solved a few of them with `pip install ...`.

And then it asked me for eventlog (`ImportError: No module named eventlog`). I tried `pip install eventlog` and this is what I got:

```
Collecting eventlog
Downloading eventlog-0.11.0.tar.gz
Collecting django-jsonfield>=0.8.11 (from eventlog)
Downloading django-jsonfield-0.9.15.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: django-jsonfield, eventlog
Running setup.py install for django-jsonfield
Running setup.py install for eventlog
Successfully installed django-jsonfield-0.9.15 eventlog-0.11.0
```

So from this I guess it went well but I still get the same error. Here's the whole traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 119, in create
import_module(entry)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named eventlog
```

Is it the wrong eventlog, or do I need to further configure eventlog to make it visible to django?

Thanks in adavance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include `eventlog` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

It should look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'eventlog',
    ...
)
```

Source: [Official documentation](http://eventlog.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: actually I went there and I see that the installed app it's waiting for is pinax.eventlog. Thanks for the tip I just have to find how to install the eventlog of pinax

Comment: Same procedure as for `eventlog`: http://pinax-eventlog.readthedocs.org/en/latest/